# How to break word in Bootstrap responsive Table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my code:

```
 <table id="table"
      class="dataTable table table-hover table-md table-responsive" cellspacing="0" role="grid">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>S1</th>
          <th>S2</th>
          <th>S3</th>
          <th word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 160px;max-width: 160px; >A long worddddd</th>
          <th>Another long word</th>
          <th>Word4</th>
          <th>S5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

This is the HTML code for my bootstrap responsive table, I want to break long word, but I tried applying style, making classes but nothing is possible, I tried other solutions on SO as well, but they are not working.
If someone could please help me out.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use inline style, you could use this:

```
<th style="word-wrap: break-word; min-width: 160px; max-width: 160px;">A long worddddd</th>
```

If you want to use class, you could use this in your html file:

```
<th class="your-class-name">A long worddddd</th>
```

and in your css file/section:

```
.your-class-name {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 160px;
}
```